# How can I remove the service name prefix in PyCharm when using the docker-compose interpreter type?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pycharm

I have created a simple app using `docker-compose` and its PyCharm support.  I've configured a docker-compose interpreter using PyCharm's GUI.  I want to run a `pytest` test using that interpreter, and enter the debugger.  The problem is that when I enter the debugger, the service name (`app_1`) is prepended to all of the container output.  This makes it very hard to read the session.

```
Recreating docker-compose-demo_app_1 ... 
Attaching to docker-compose-demo_app_1
Connected to pydev debugger (build 213.5744.248)
app_1  | Launching pytest with arguments test_foo.py::test_foo --no-header --no-summary -q in /opt/project
app_1  | 
app_1  |app_1  | ============================= test session starts ==============================
app_1  | collecting ... collected 1 item
app_1  |app_1  | 
app_1  | test_foo.py::test_foo ##teamcity[testSuiteStarted timestamp='2022-02-15T16:20:52.396' locationHint='python</opt/project>://test_foo' name='test_foo' nodeId='1' parentNodeId='0']
app_1  |>>> 42
app_1  | PyDev console: starting.
app_1  | 
app_1  | 42
>>>
```

Here I've evaluated the expression `42`, you can see my text entered after the prompt.

I see that `docker-compose logs` has a `--no-log-prefix` option that can apparently hide these logs, but as the interpreter configuration in PyCharm doesn't seem to expose any way to pass options to `docker-compose`, I don't know if I can use this option.  Is there any way to get a cleaner output at the console?

Comment: Try this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#run

Comment: @ZalakBhalani What part of that specifically?  I already have a working run configuration for pytest and for my server (in this case Flask).  The service name `app_1` still gets prepended to all the output.

Comment: @amoe currently there is no way you can pass flags to docker compose there is a ticket for that feature https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-249542

Comment: Looks like it is possible to add options into the "Command and options" field in a Python run configuration with a docker-compose interpreter.  However PyCharm doesn't recognize the `--no-log-prefix` option even though it is valid for the `up`command now.  I think it has a hardcoded whitelist of options somewhere.